# How thick of an arched concrete slab needed for root cellar roof

Tags: concrete, load-bearing, concrete-block

We are building a 6' x 6' root cellar with a dirt floor and concrete block walls.  The walls will be on 16"w x 12"d concrete footings and 1/2" vertical rebar every 3rd hole. (~24" on center)  All holes will be filled with concrete.

I would like to build an arched roof for the top of the cellar, similar to this one:

[image: Arched concrete slab form with rebar]

The root cellar will then be covered with up to 4 feet of rocky, sandy soil on top of it.  We live in a high desert (dry) climate, so moisture and drainage should not be an issue for us.

My main question is: how thick should I pour the arched slab?

Thanks!

Comment: Seeing you will be under the very heavy concrete slab sometimes, you really should have an engineer design it, instead of internet want to bees.  If not done right, it will hurt a lot more than stepping on a leggo block in bare feet.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How did you determine the size of the footings?

Comment: size of the footings was done via internet research.  I may end up making them deeper to be safe, but everything I read seemed to say 2x the width of the block for width.

Comment: Size of footings usually has more to do with the soil conditions.  2x the width of the block might be more of a rule of thumb for general use.  Other factors will adjust this measurement.

Comment: The degree of arch and extent of reenforcing both play into the correct answer for this. That's a pretty shallow/flat arch in your example.  4 feet of soil over it is quite a load. The advice above to get professional help which can ensure that it's *adequate* while also not being excessively expensive by choosing *overkill* is sound, IMHO. You might also be able do something else, such as buying a section of 6 foot diameter precast sewer pipe or well casing and cutting it in half to make the roof as a full barrel arch (which is, generally, far stronger than a low arch as illustrated.)

Comment: I hadn't thought about the sewer/corrugated pipe option.  I really like that idea.  Thank you!!

Comment: @Ecnerwal a concrete pipe (well, any pipe) needs full soil surround to be structurally sound.  Once you cut it in half, you lose a big part of its resistance to soil pressure.  There do exist precast arch structures (ConSpan, et al.) that will do what the OP wants, but these are actually *engineered* to be bottomless.

Comment: If you're going to use a pipe, use the whole round, then build up the floor in it for the shape that you want.